# helm delete release stuck in status DELETING

Tags: kubernetes

It appears I'm unable to delete a helm release. The status gets stuck in DELETING, the kubernetes associated cleanup job fails aswell without saying anything what might cause it to fail.

Do you guys experienced such behavior before ? How can this be solved ?. I've also run the kubectl command, used in the cleanup container, individually and still nothing.

Thank you !.

Here the attached command outputs:

```
helm ls --all prometheus-operator --debug

NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                           APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
prometheus-operator     1               Mon Aug  5 17:22:14 2019        DELETING        prometheus-operator-6.3.1       0.31.1          monitoring
prometheus-operator-v2  1               Mon Aug  5 19:26:20 2019        DEPLOYED        prometheus-operator-6.4.0       0.31.1          monitoring
```

```
kubectl get job prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup -n monitoring

NAME                                   COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup   0/1           19h        19h
```

```
kubectl describe jobs/prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup -n monitoring

Name:           prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup
Namespace:      monitoring
Selector:       controller-uid=c6bfd107-b79a-11e9-a527-42010aa80121
Labels:         app=prometheus-operator-operator
                chart=prometheus-operator-6.3.1
                heritage=Tiller
                release=prometheus-operator
Annotations:    helm.sh/hook: pre-delete
                helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: hook-succeeded
                helm.sh/hook-weight: 3
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Mon, 05 Aug 2019 19:04:59 +0300
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=prometheus-operator-operator
                    chart=prometheus-operator-6.3.1
                    controller-uid=c6bfd107-b79a-11e9-a527-42010aa80121
                    heritage=Tiller
                    job-name=prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup
                    release=prometheus-operator
  Service Account:  prometheus-operator-operator
  Containers:
   kubectl:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/hyperkube:v1.12.1
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      kubectl delete alertmanager   --all; kubectl delete prometheus     --all; kubectl delete prometheusrule --all; kubectl delete servicemonitor --all; sleep 10; kubectl delete crd alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com; kubectl delete crd prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com; kubectl delete crd prometheusrules.monitoring.coreos.com; kubectl delete crd servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com; kubectl delete crd podmonitors.monitoring.coreos.com;

    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:           <none>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Not sure why I hadn't have any Events in the job description but ran the deletion again and was able to check the spawned cleanup pod logs:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring:prometheus-operator-operator" cannot list resource "prometheuses" in API group "monitoring.coreos.com" in the namespace "monitoring"
```

The issue was caused by an incomplete helm release deletion ( interrupted ). During this deletion, the prometheus operator's service account and his associated clusterrolebinding+clusterrole got removed, and upon a second helm delete try it was missing the needed permissions to delete everything else that left undeleted from the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35453792/2898919).

You probably just need to:

`kubectl edit jobs/prometheus-operator-operator-cleanup -n monitoring` 
and remove finalizers block from resource.